# Development in IIS or Visual Studio internal webserver

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2010, webserver, cassini

Do you do local development/debugging with the internal webserver or a local iis install? I'm currently running the internal VS2010 webserver but it's so slow it hurts. I can see the page rendering in front of me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use Windows Server 2008 as my development machine so that I can use IIS 7 as the web server and just set the default location of the website to a locally mapped DNS name. This especially helps when testing code that is dependent on domain URIs and other information of that nature.

One problem I have experienced is an intermittence in the ability of studio to bind the debugger to the IIS processes. (sometimes a reboot is required to get studio to bind if this happens)

Comment: you can try using VSCommands's feature 'Attach to Local IIS' instead of rebooting (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf)

Comment: @Registered User - Yah, I went through all of that when it was happening. The problem was that the debugger was actually crashing. It would build, attach, then crash. It stopped a little while back during some update (I forget which one). I don't know if it was a known bug they fixed or if the update accidentally fixed something that was hosed.